# Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. If $X$ and $Y$ are integrable r.v., then $X + Y$ is an integrable r.v.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

If $X$ and $Y$ are integrable random variables, then $X + Y$ is an integrable random variable.

Here is my attempt.

To begin with, let us notice that $X = X^{+} - X^{-}$ and $Y = Y^{+} - Y^{-}$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are integrable, it means that $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < +\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(|Y|) < +\infty$. We have to prove that $E(X + Y) < +\infty$. Indeed, given that $X^{+} \geq 0$ and $X^{-}\geq 0$, there are two sequences of non-negative and non-decreasing random variables $X^{+}_{n}$ and $X^{-}_{n}$ such that $X^{+}_{n}\to X^{+}$ and $X^{-}_{n}\to X^{-}$. Similarly, we can also state there exist two sequences of non-negative and non-decreasing random variables $Y^{+}$ and $Y^{-}$ such that $Y^{+}_{n}\to Y_{n}$ and $Y^{-}_{n}\to Y^{-}$. Hence, the monotone convergence theorem ensures us that $\mathbb{E}(X^{+}_{n})\to\mathbb{E}(X^{+})$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^{-}_{n})\to\mathbb{E}(X^{-})$ (similar results for $Y^{+}$ and $Y^{-}$).

Finally, gathering these results and the assumption given in the problem setting, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(|X + Y|) & = \mathbb{E}(|X^{+} - X^{-} + Y^{+} - Y^{-}|)\\\\
& \leq \mathbb{E}(X^{+} + X^{-} + Y^{+} + Y^{-})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty}X^{+}_{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}X^{-}_{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}Y^{+}_{n} + \lim_{n\to\infty}Y^{-}_{n})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty} X^{+}_{n}) + \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty} X^{-}_{n}) + \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty} Y^{+}_{n}) + \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty} Y^{-}_{n})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(X^{+}) + \mathbb{E}(X^{-}) + \mathbb{E}(Y^{+}) + \mathbb{E}(Y^{-})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(|X|) + \mathbb{E}(|Y|) < +\infty
\end{align*}

Can someone please check out my solution?

Comment: @BrianMoehring It has already been proved the linearity of the operator $\mathbb{E}$ by the time the question has been asked as well as its monotonicity.

Comment: All right, then you should simplify the proof to $$\mathbb{E}(|X+Y|) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|+|Y|) = \mathbb{E}(|X|) + \mathbb{E}(|Y|) < +\infty$$  All the parts about the positive and negative parts, as well as the sequences, are unnecessary.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you very much! Anyway,  the proposed solution is also correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  The only criticism I'd have is that the inequality in the second line both removes the absolute values and introduces the sequences, so in the scheme of the proof, it's not clear whether you think the limits are required to remove the absolute values as you've done (of course they aren't... it's just the triangle inequality)